# Have two different libraries with same properties - Swing

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to have two libraries **import java.awt.Font;** and **import com.itextpdf.text.Font;** one for GUI and second one for pdf generator, I get an error as soon as I import the second library. [image: [error]]

If I comment the first library I get an error, [image: [an error]]

and if I comment the second library I get an error [image: [error,]]

How to resolve this, thanks.

Comment: Basically, the compile can't destination between the two types of `Font` class.  Import one and explicitly reference the other.  That is, if you import `com.itextpdf.text.Font`, but want to use `java.awt.Font`, you will need to use the full package name, `java.awt.Font font = ...;`

Comment: You cannot import both, you can only import one `Font` the other needs to be referenced with the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just forget about imports, and refer to the fully qualified class names instead, like:

`java.awt.Font myFont = new java.awt.Font();`

Comment: Thanks @Michael, when I [tried](http://i.imgur.com/NBffQnY.png), can't find myFont.setFont() property, I don't know where I am going wrong, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding setFont() : I don't think java.awt.Font has such a method. I suppose you might be trying to call the method setFont() of a different object, and pass the Font 'myFont' along?
as in: myObject.setFont(myFont);

Comment: Thanks @Michael, have fixed the problem, with your help, thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the library **import com.itextpdf.text.Font;** as it is and removed the library **import java.awt.Font;**, based on comments provided by 'Michael', 'MadProgrammer' and 'M. Deinum'.

Referred the (library directly) fully qualified class @

```
//path/name label
JLabel lblPathname = new JLabel("Path/name:");
lblPathname.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 12));
lblPathname.setBounds(334, 682, 63, 14);
frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(lblPathname);
```

would solved the problem.

instead,

```
lblPathname.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 12));
```